# Hide dropdowns in loop on click outside

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of values which would render a list with a dropdown menu.
I would show/hide the dropdown on click of an element.

```
 projectData.map(project => (
  <div>
    <div>{project.name}</div>
    <div
      onClick={() => setDropdownId((prevState) => (
        prevState === project.id ? null : project.id)
      )}
    >
      Show
    </div>
    {dropdownId === project.id && (
      <ul className="dropdown">
        <li>option</li>
      </ul>
    )}
  </div>
))
```

How can I hide the opened dropdown on outside click?
I tried with ref but is not working as expected as the elements are in a loop.

Comment: One way is just using the right element - `select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use onBlur to trigger changes when loosing focuse

```
handleBlur = (e) => {
 // add you code here
}

projectData.map(project => (
  <div>
    <div>{project.name}</div>
    <div
      onBlur={handleBlur}
      onClick={() => setDropdownId((prevState) => (
        prevState === project.id ? null : project.id)
      )}
    >
      Show
    </div>
    {dropdownId === project.id && (
      <ul className="dropdown">
        <li>option</li>
      </ul>
    )}
  </div>
))
```

Comment: Thanks.It worked. I needed to add role="button" and tabIndex  though.